# Unable to parse chinese and french characters in XML with groovy and HTTP request

Tags: xml, encoding, groovy, soapui, content-type

Below is the code to read a XML from a simple XML file on disk. It contains the Chinese and french characters. It works perfectly fine and displays the characters correctly.

---

Plugin available on Github:-
https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console.git/tags/7.0.1

---

Code Snippet (Written in Groovy Console Plugin with AEM 6)

```
 String file = "C:\\data\\create.xml";
     String line = "";
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"UTF-8"));
     while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
         sb.append(line);
     }
     def xmlf = new XmlSlurper().parseText(sb.toString())
        .declareNamespace(gContact:'http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008',
            gd:'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005')

     println xmlf.title
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
  xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
  term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact' />
<title type='text'>Elizabeth Bennet 反常的矛盾 degrés la réalité pourrions réessayer</title>

</entry>
```

Response:-

```
Elizabeth Bennet 反常的矛盾 degrés la réalité pourrions réessayer
```

But now i mock the same xml with SOAP UI Rest request and consume it using HTTPClient it does not work for chinese characters. I have tried with both UTF-8 an ISO-8859-1. Also using getResponseBodyAsStream and AsString does not work. Please Help. Below is the code and current response.

Code Snippet (Written in Groovy Console Plugin ver 7.01 with AEM 6)

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
    String importUrl = "http://localhost:8080/xml/node"
    HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(importUrl)
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
         new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));
    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
    byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody()
    println new String(responseBody)
```

Current Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
  xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
  term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact' />
<title type='text'>Elizabeth Bennet ????? degrés la réalité pourrions réessayer</title>

</entry>
```

Comment: ISO-8859-1 will never be able to contain chinese characters.

Comment: I initially placed ISO-8859-1 for the french characters. But with chinese characters i am having the hard time. Could you assist in what could be done. Many Regards

Comment: Use UTF-8. That can represent any character you want. Note the new String(responseBody) uses the platform default encoding. You should never use that. Specify an encoding explicitely: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29

Comment: I have already tried that, but with HTTP Get Method it is also not able to fulfill the purpose and i just see ???? in place of my chinese text. But surprisingly when i read it from a file, it works with UTF 8

Comment: One more interesting thing i observed was that when i give encoding="UTF-8" in my XML, it simply stops to render on the browser.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you know you don't need all the string buffer stuff in your first solution? Use `parse ` instead of `parseText`

Comment: SoapUI is probably not doing the right thing. Try writing the bytes you receive (without transforming them to string) to a file, and open the file. Also check the HTTP headers with your browser console and check what the encoding is.

Comment: @JBNizet :- with new String(responseBody, "UTF-8") instead of only new String(responseBody) the french characters are also distorted now. Elizabeth Bennet ????? degr�s la r�alit� pourrions r�essayer

Comment: @tim_yates- thanks for the suggestion, also please let me know what to do in the latter case.

Comment: That probably means SoapUI is not sending the response body in the right encoding.

Comment: Hmm.....let me try once using POSTMAN then....I will let you know.

Comment: Chinese characters need Unicode (node UTF8).

Comment: @jdweng :- exactly. I tried with UTF-8 it worked.

Comment: @JBNizet :- You were absolutely right. The SOAP UI was messing with the header information. I compiled my code and used it directly in my application it worked like a charm with UTF-8 and string parametrized constructor. :) Thanks a ton